# How do I shove a pane to the left in tmux?

Tags: tmux

Suppose I have three horizontal panes stacked up vertically and I would like to push one of them to the far left, such the other two panes are still stacked but on the right.

Current Setup:

```
Pane 1
----------
Pane 2
----------
Pane 2
```

Desired setup

```
Pane 1 | Pane 2
       | Pane 3
```

What is the correct command for doing this?
I have already checked the man page, but could not find this specific functionality.

Answer (score 9):

I've run into this problem a few times and google is utterly useless.  Luckily the [man page](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=tmux&sektion=1) isn't too difficult to read.  And documenting this will provide a quick reminder the next time I forget.

The command you're looking for is `move-pane`.

You'll have to run it a couple times.  I've reindexed the pane numbers to match tmux's convention.  Since Pane 0 ultimately borders the other two panes, you should imagine that you're moving Pane 1 (right of 0), and then moving Pane 2 (below Pane 1).

```
┌──────┐                            ┌──────┬──────┐
│Pane 0│    PREFIX + :              │Pane 0│Pane 1│
├──────┤    move-pane -h -s 1 -t 0  │      │      │
│Pane 1│                            ├──────┴──────┤
├──────┤                            │Pane 2       │
│Pane 2│                            │             │
└──────┘                            └─────────────┘
                                    ┌──────┬──────┐
            PREFIX + :              │Pane 0│Pane 1│
            move-pane -v -s 2 -t 1  │      │      │
                                    │      ├──────┤
                                    │      │Pane 2│
                                    │      │      │
                                    └──────┴──────┘
```

Here are rough keybindings to achieve the same.  Just make sure to focus the pane that will move first.

```
bind-key g command-prompt -p "place below. select target window" "move-pane -h -t %%"
bind-key G command-prompt -p "place right of. select target window" "move-pane -h -t %%"
```

If you have trouble figuring out the pane numbers, remember that the number is assigned by order, the number doesn't stick with any particular pane.  Use a keybinding to display the pane numbers before each movement.  The default is `PREFIX + q`.  If yours is different, you can use `PREFIX + ?` to find it.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand what you mean try with:

```
PREFIX + %   # Create a vertical split
PREFIX + "   # In right pane create a horizontal split
```

Starting with only one pane. By default PREFIX = `Ctrl + b`, move between panes with `PREFIX + q` then type pane number.

**EDIT**: Wait wait(I didn't take into account that the panes already exist), try with this:

```
PREFIX + SPACE
```

Try this various times until the arrangement is the desired.